# Infinite loop in my logic in code

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm working a program and I'm not sure whats wrong with my program, It all seems to work out fine but when I go to run the program, it doesn't stop.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Random_Numbers_2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int counter = 0;
      do{
      String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the number of tries: ");
      final int TRIES = Integer.parseInt(response);
      int dice = 1;
      while(dice != -1)
      {
      while(dice <= TRIES)
      {
         int d1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
         int d2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
         dice++;
         String response_2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, d1 + "   " + d2 + "\n" + "Enter any number to continue, it will not effect the program" + "\n" + "Please enter -1 when doubles show", "Dice Generator" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
         double dice_2 = Double.parseDouble(response_2);      
      }
      }
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to run it again? ", "Dice Generator" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
  }while(counter == 0);
 }
}
```

Comment: why do you have two while loops ? one for dice != -1 and one for dice <=TRIES ??

Comment: Plus the do-while(counter==0) around the whole program. Get rid of all of the extra loops.

Comment: idk im just trying to make the program work is is bad for two while loops?

Comment: You want to combine them into a single while (dice != 1 && dice <= TRIES) assuming the logic of the two expressions are correct.

Comment: `dice` never become -1. So, the second while loops forever

Comment: how would i make the loop stop

Answer (score 1):

Its infinite because dice value will never be -1. Combine two loops together.

It will still be infinite because counter will always be zero, redirect the input of continue or not to counter variable.

PFB the refactored code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int counter = 1;
    do{
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the number of tries: ");
        final int TRIES = Integer.parseInt(response);
        int dice = 1;
        double dice_2 = 0;
        while(dice_2 != -1 || dice <= TRIES)
            {
                int d1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                dice++;
                String response_2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, d1 + "   " + d2 + "\n" + "Enter any number to continue, it will not effect the program" + "\n" + "Please enter -1 when doubles show", "Dice Generator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                dice_2 = Double.parseDouble(response_2);
            }
        counter = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to run it again? ", "Dice Generator" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(counter);
    }while(counter == 0);
}
```

Comment: What has not worked? Is it still infinjte loop - please take thw edited code. I have edited and tested as well. Please mark as answered if it answers your query.

Comment: The code is working. Upvoted it. Suggest to apply  `if((response_2 != null) && ! response_2.isEmpty())` before `parseDouble` and `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

Please review, and ask if it is not clear:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int stop = 1; 
        while(stop != 0) //loop to control re-runs 
        {
            String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the number of tries: ");
            final int TRIES = Integer.parseInt(response);
            int dice = 1;
            while((dice <= TRIES) && (stop != 0)) //loop to control re-tries 
            {
                int d1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                int d2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                dice++;

                stop = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, d1 + "   " + d2 +"\n Quit game? ", "Dice Generator" , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
     }
```